# Crop and resize images in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to crop and resize the images. When images moved to the resized_images folder all images are turn to black but images are resized(535 * 313). Here is my code i have tried so far. Can you please suggest me right way to do this.? thank u

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="input-6" name="slideshow_images[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
 <input type="submit" name="sub" >
 </form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
$pic =  $_FILES["slideshow_images"]["name"];  
foreach($pic as $pic_src)
{   
 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($pic_src);
$filename =  'resized_images/'.$pic_src.'cropped_whatever.jpeg';

$thumb_width = 535;

$thumb_height = 313;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
  
$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;
 
if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
   // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
   $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
   // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
   $new_width = $thumb_width;
    
   $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);

    
   
 }

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                   0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                   0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height,
                   $width, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 80);
}

}
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code lines to:

```
$pic =  $_FILES["slideshow_images"]["tmp_name"];

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(($pic_src)));
```

Because ["name"] is only 123.jpg, it is not object.

The best way will be that:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="input-6" name="slideshow_images[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
 <input type="submit" name="sub" >
 </form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
  if(isset($_FILES['slideshow_images'])){
    foreach ($_FILES["slideshow_images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
      if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["slideshow_images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["slideshow_images"]["name"][$key];
          $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(($tmp_name)));
          $filename = 'images/'.$name.'cropped_whatever.jpg';
          $thumb_width = 535;

          $thumb_height = 313;

          $width = imagesx($image);
          $height = imagesy($image);

          $original_aspect = $width / $height;
          $thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

          if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
          {
             // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
             $new_height = $thumb_height;
             $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
          }
          else
          {
             // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
             $new_width = $thumb_width;

             $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);



           }

          $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

          // Resize and crop
          imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                             $image,
                             0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                             0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                             0, 0,
                             $new_width, $new_height,
                             $width, $height);
          imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 80);
      }
    }
  }
}
  ?>
```

Also, If you don't want to add ".jpg" in filename, replace $filename row to this:

```
$filename = 'images/'.preg_replace('/\.[^.]*$/', '', $name).'cropped_whatever.jpg';
```

Comment: Ya i did the above changes but images are not moving to the folder

Comment: @Salman : Did you really mean the images are NOT moving to the folder?  Also, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. it has some things there you might want to think about. :-)

Comment: because now $pic_src contains path to file, not it name. You can don't use $pic_src  variable in filename or just parse all $_FILES array and after that use keys to choose path, file_name

Comment: @Salman : Have you checked the returning values for each function call?  The "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure."? This would show you if each step made it through ok.

Comment: @Mark Manning : I dont want to fill new color, just i want display same images what i have uploaded. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Salman - Yes it is. AlexIL had two good points I should have caught (Thanks AlexIL!). Salman - You have to think about this like a painter's canvas. Painters normally put what they call a "wash" onto the canvas first so their painting shows up better.  Same here. What I'm suggesting is to ensure the background is set up right first and THEN paint over it with your image. So first you fill the image with some color like white that has no transparency and then repaint it with the image copy.

Comment: have made some changes in code, please check it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  What the problem is is the background color is black and totally transparent.  What you have to do is just allocate a true color (like white) with alpha and make the alpha totally non-transparent. Then just do a filled rectangle over the new area first and your image should then show up. :-)

The following is directly out of the php documentation about imagecopy:

```
// create new image with padding
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($right-$left+$padding*2,$bottom-$top+$padding*2);
// Allocate background color
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha( $img, 255, 255, 255, 0 );
// fill the background
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);
// or use
imagefilledrectangle( $img, 0,0,$width,$height, $white );
// copy
imagecopy($img, $image, $padding, $padding, $left, $top, $right-$left, $bottom-$top);
```

Notice that they do an imagefill with the background color before actually copying the new image.  It is the same for the imagecopyresample.

Well, unlike before - this time I didn't get a black image. So check what you do against the following:  In fact, download the following and run it (along with the test.jpg image).  See if it works for you. Please note that this is directly out of the PHP Documentation website for imagecopyresample.

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = './test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, "new.jpg", 100);
?>
```

And here is the image:

[image]

And here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Where should i allocate a true color.please reply

Comment: Before you do the imagecopyresample and the imagefill or imagefilledrectangle also.  Otherwise it doesn't do a lot of good. :-) Modified answer.

Comment: I dont want to fill new color, just i want display same images what i have uploaded.Is it possible ?

Comment: What was happening to me is since the background was transparent, the new colors applied via the imagecopyresample() function just didn't change the transparency information.  So what you may need to do is to reset it to not being transparent.  Then all incoming colors are just applied to the RGB part and the A remains the same. That is what was happening to me when I tried to use the resample function. You need to break it down into each step so you are ensured you are getting what you want. Do an imagejpeg after each step. Write to a temp file.

Comment: Can you please send me imagecopyresample() function code.Thank u

Comment: @Salman - there is no way to e-mail it to you but I will modify my answer again with a short script just to create a resampled image.

Comment: @ Mark Manning : Thank u.